# Complex regex: key-value pairs

Tags: c#, regex

I am failing to figure out the correct regex for this type of data:

> Phone-Work: 1111111111 Phone-Fax Work: 222222222 Phone-General:
>   (333) 333-3333 Email-: email@email.com

Desired result is:

```
Col1    Col2       Col3
Phone   Work       1111111111 
Phone   Fax Work   222222222 
Phone   General    (333) 333-3333
Email   null       email@email.com
```

The key consists of two parts(the second may be missing):
`Phone-Work:`, `Email-:`

There can be 4 types of keys: `Phone-`, `Email-`, `User ID-`, `Web address-`

I am failing to figure out how to create a regex that will take the `value` part and stop before new `key`.

Here is what I am trying with some data:

https://regex101.com/r/weEc3A/1

Comment: Well, you might use this - [`(?sim)(Phone|Email|User ID|Web address)-([^:]*):\s*((?:(?!(?:Phone|Email|User ID|Web address)-).)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/ClS8zm/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, !!!! can you add that as an answer? And what is `(?sim)`

Comment: Sorry, `m` is redundant.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, about the `(?...)`, see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a solution like

```
(?si)(Phone|Email|User ID|Web address)-([^:]*):\s*((?:(?!(?:Phone|Email|User ID|Web address)-).)*)
```

that is an equivalent of

```
(?si)(Phone|Email|User ID|Web address)-([^:]*):\s*(.*?)(?=(?:Phone|Email|User ID|Web address)-|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ClS8zm/2)

**Details**:

- `(Phone|Email|User ID|Web address)-` - matches the possible starting values followed with `-` capturing that into Group 1
- `([^:]*)` - captures zero or more chars other than `:` into Group 2
- `:\s*` - a colon followed with zero or more whitespaces
- `((?:(?!(?:Phone|Email|User ID|Web address)-).)*)` - Group 3 capturing any char (`.`) that is not starting the sequence matched with `(?:Phone|Email|User ID|Web address)-` pattern.

Since `(?s)` modifier is used, the `.` matches a newline, too. In C#, you may use `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag instead of this inline option.  The `(?i)` is the inline equivalent of the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag. When combined, the inline modifiers can be written inside one pair of parentheses: `(?si)`.

Comment: Probably it is very difficult to implement this for any key? I suspect it will be impossible to detect the end of the value?

Comment: By enabling case insensitive matching, I'd not write `Phone|Email|...`, but rather `phone|email|...` (I know both work, but IMO the latter is less confusing)

Comment: When you have a specific pattern, you might try to use that pattern instead of the key list. If the key list is not large, you can use this approach. You also may build the alternation dynamically.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thank you so so much! I was hoping you will be answering my question when posting :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one is a start for you :

```
(.*?)-(.*?):\s*([- ()+\w@.]+)(?![-\w]*:)
```

Comment: IMO little bit too _generic_, there are constraints that may be used to make it more reliable. To mention that regex to match phone numbers and (especially) e-mails are much much much more convoluted than this...

Comment: Yes but data in the regex101 sample are very generic so i give this. And I think i'ts easy to specialize some of this match group if you want.